# Extended Collatz conjecture

Tags: collatz-conjecture

As you all know, the Collatz conjecture claims that any positive integer will eventrually be reduced to 1 by appllying the sequence $n_{i+1} = x*n_{i} + 1$, when $n_{i}$ is odd, and $n_{i+1} = n_{i} / 2$, when $n_i$ is even, where $x = 3$.

I decided to extend Collatz conjecture and consider the same function for any other $x$. It turned out that already at $x = 5$ almost all sequences formed by the number n went to infinity, that is, its terms rapidly increased.

Then I decided to find the numbers x at which cycles exist (that is, starting from which the sequence will repeat itself). I decided not to consider cycles consisting only of the number 1, because they are easy to solve: {1} is a cycle for any number $x$, which can be represented as $2^k - 1$, and only for such a number.

I came to the following formula:
$$
n = \frac{x^{k-1} + x^{k-2} * 2^{a_1} + ... + x^{0}*2^{a_{k-1}}}{2^{a_{k}} - x^k}
$$, where $k$ is length of the cycle, $n$ is the smallest number of the cycle, each member of the set $a$ is greater than the previous one, and for each $m$ it is true that $2^{a_{m}} < (x+1)^m$. And of course, all variables are integers and natural non-zero numbers.

I wrote a programm, that finds every soluation for this equation. The programm found all solutions for $a_k < 45$, and they were `{1, 3}, x = 5`, `{13, 33, 83}, x = 5`, `{17, 43, 27}, x = 5`, `{27, 611}, x = 181` and `{35, 99}, x = 181`.

*The question is, can you find more cycles for different x, or **are the numbers 5 and 181 the only numbers, for which there are cycles, different from {1}**?*

Comment: I don't understand what $a_k$ is, in "$a_k<45$". Is it the smallest number in a cycle?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A267969 is related.

Comment: Gottfried Heims found the $5$ and $181$ cycles at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507762/generalizations-of-the-collatz-to-mx-pm-1-2-for-m-181-gives-two-nontrivia and later noted that Crandall had found them earlier, Crandall, R.  (1978).  On the ”3x+1” problem. Mathematics of Computation, 1281–1292.

Comment: @GerryMyerson moral: It is probably futile to work on Collatz-related matters unless you first master the literature on the subject.  [That is probably true about any other mathematical area, but Collatz seems to attract more amateurs that most areas.]

Comment: $a_k$ is how many pair numbers there are in the cycle

Comment: Btw. up to which $x$ did you test?

Comment: After noticing, that ***trivial*** cycles occur * in the positive numbers : if $x = 2^j-1$ and * in the negative numbers: if $x=2^j+1$. ---- ... it might be interesting that the only so far found ***nontrivial*** cycles are with $x=4k+1$ ($x \in \{5,181\}$) in the ***positive*** numbers and with  $x=4k-1$ ($x \in \{3\}$) in the ***negative*** numbers. So, for $x=4k-1 \gt 3$ there seem to be no nontrivial cycles in the positive numbers at all. However, after some small attacks I couldn't make something out of this so far.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I also discovered that $5$ and $181$ can be represented as $k^2 + (k+1)^2$, where $k = (2^n - 1)^2$. Next such number is **4901**.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I checked all possible options when $a_k <= 216$, and I didn’t find anything other than the above cycles. I haven't tested any specific values of x, and all I can say is that if there is a loop with factor $x$ and length $k$, then $(x+1)^k > 2^{216}$